# Dynamic Web Page News Feed

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a side bar in my lab's website that will pull the first three items off the news page and show them in the side bar on every other page in the website. I've been looking around and all I have found so far is that it is common to use php and a sql database to do what I want. The only problems with that are that I don't know php and I don't have access to a sql database for this site. Is there any example code that could at least get me started with this news feed or is it not possible without a database?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is only achievable with a CMS and PHP. HTML is for static pages, PHP creates dynamic pages. The good news is you don't need to know that much about PHP or databases to implement a news feed on your site. Content Management Systems like Wordpress and Drupal do all the hard work in the background. Depending on how large your lab's site is now, and how badly you want a news feed on it, it might be worthwhile switching over to a CMS, and you might find the move painless.

On Wordpress, a news feed is often built with a PHP function called 'query_posts.'
You can read about it here: [Wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

And, way simpler, you can do what de-bugged suggested, and find a newsfeed widget. These are available through Content Management Systems. Other people code them, you drag and drop them into your site. And they're completely customizable.

Here is one available on Wordpress:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-news-feed-widget/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Is your labs website based on some CMS? If so you could check out for some newsfeed widgets for modules.

For other site you could try [feedzilla](http://widgets.feedzilla.com/news/builder/index.html)